# asp.net vb.net gridview, get row id when pressing template field button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a template field with a button. I want to press the button and get the row Id so I can return the users selection. I have a regular select button which works fine but the user want the people who are not employee’s to hide the select button. I have this working but since it’s a template field it fires the RoW_command procedure and I cannot seem to get the row index since it is a template field and not the regular Select button. Or I cannot seem to name the Regular select button since it Command field does not have a Name or ID property?

Like I said this works hiding the template field called btnSelect
  Private Sub GridView3_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowDataBound

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "LegacyPersonType") <> "Employee") Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow ' This will make row back color yellow 
            e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect").Visible = False

        Else
            e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White   ' the normal employees make white
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

I need to find the Row index  when I press btnSelect
Private Sub GridView3_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowCommand

```
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) ‘ Error invalid
```

‘ in other words when pressing the tem-plate field there is no e.CommandArgument 
‘But clicking the regular select there is

```
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView3.Rows(index)
    Session("EnterpriseID") = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView3.Rows(index).Cells(2).Text)
    Dim EmployeeType As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView3.Rows(index).Cells(7).Text)
    Dim CommonName As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView3.Rows(index).Cells(1).Text)

    Dim EnterpriseID = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView3.Rows(index).Cells(6).Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself, I made the default Select button on the grid a Template field. since it was the default button it had the necessary code to make it fire. This was the problem with making a template field from scratch. And by making it a template field it then also gave it a name. So in the RowDataBound code the FindControl method above hides it when a person is not an employee. – R2 Builder 1 min ago edit

Answer (score 0):

The `GridViewRow` object knows its row index via the `RowIndex` property in the `RowCommand` event, like this:

```
Private Sub GridView3_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowCommand
    ' Get the row by finding the grandparent of the control (button) 
    ' that initiated the command
    Dim theGridViewRow As GridViewRow
    theGridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Button).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

    ' Get the index value from the grid view row
    Dim index As Integer = theGridViewRow.RowIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub GridView3_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowCommand
        Dim index As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex'    I get this Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs.Friend ReadOnly Property Row As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. C:\Users\z533560\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Recognition\AddNew3.aspx.vb 166 32 Recognition '' Normally I use that in the GridView3_RowDataBound, If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow

Comment: @R2Builder - I have updated the answer to walk up the hierarchy to find the grid view row relative to the button that invoked the command.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.  on this line theGridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Button).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

Comment: the Goal is to hide a button on whatever row, then if the button is not hidden, be able to select it and get the row Id to pass back. Any Ideas?